# Book about crowns that enhance mental abilities

Tags: story-identification, novel, hard-sci-fi

I am looking for a book set in the future in "outer space" where children wear different colored crowns that enhance mental abilities.

The book starts at a boarding school where the kids are going home for the holidays. The kids travel by a spaceship set up like a bus. When there are only a few children left the "bus" crashes on a planet where there are "crowns" that help enhance mental abilities.

Comment: When did you read this book?  Was it a hardcover, a paperback, or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: https://shanshad1.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/reviews-hyperspace-high-by-zac-harrison/ is a boarding school in space, but no mention of intelligence enhancing crowns that I can see.